# How can I play a series of short mp3 files with no gap between them in Android?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have a lot of short .mp3 files that I want to play one after the other.. I tried to use onCompletion event and start the next mp3, though this causes a brief gap between the 2 mp3s..

Here is the code:

```
void StartSound() {
    mediaplayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(FILE_PATH + counter + ".mp3"));

    try {
        mediaplayer.start();
        mediaplayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                                     counter++;
                 try {
                  mp.reset();
                  mp.setDataSource(FILE_PATH + counter + ".mp3");
                  mp.prepare();

                 } catch (Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
                 }
                 mp.start();
            }
        });

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

Is there a work around to this issue?

Comment: Load them all into one or preload them. I see only that.

Answer (score 1):

There's a workaround, but whether it's worth the trouble is up to you.

The basic idea is to decode the MP3 files to a PCM buffer, stitch them together in a byte array, and play with an `AudioTrack`. Seamless MP3 playback doesn't really exist with `MediaPlayer`. This could be a pain in the ass, though, and memory problems are likely if you're talking about full songs. For short clips, it may work, but `SoundPool` might be the better option.

If you're just trying to narrow the gap a bit, you can try preparing the following `MediaPlayer` objects before `onCompletionListener`. Instead of waiting to be done, prepare the next two so you can start playback faster. Then when you hit `onCompletion`, you can just flip which object you're using and `start()`. Crude double buffering, in a way.

Comment: Yeah I think it will rely on smart implementation. Like preloading the next track while the first one is played, but since it's short audio files..

Comment: Good point. The length of the audio files makes a big difference here. If we're talking quick sound-effect types, you should definitely go with SoundPool.

Comment: That is way out of my programming skills :) Though I'll check that, but first I'll check the preloading trick.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    private int[] tracks = {R.raw.explosion,R.raw.pianothingy_one,R.raw.car_horn_x};
    int mCompleted = 0;

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, tracks[0]);
 mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() 
 {
     @Override
     public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
     {
         mCompleted++;
         mp.reset();
         if (mCompleted < tracks.length) 
         {
             try
             {
                 AssetFileDescriptor afd = getResources().openRawResourceFd(tracks[mCompleted]);
                 if (afd != null) 
                 {
                     mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                     afd.close();
                     mp.prepare();
                     mp.start();
                 }
             }
             catch (Exception ex) 
             {
                ex.printStackTrace();
             }

         } 
         else if (mCompleted>=tracks.length) 
         {
             mCompleted =0;
             try
             {
                 AssetFileDescriptor afd = getResources().openRawResourceFd(tracks[mCompleted]);
                 if (afd != null) 
                 {
                     mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                     afd.close();
                     mp.prepare();
                     mp.start();
                 }
             }
             catch (Exception ex) 
             {
                ex.printStackTrace();
             }
         }
         else
         {
             mCompleted=0;
              mp.release();
              mp = null;
         }

     }
 });

 mp.start();
```